# Can a mail-sending program send mails under my email send?

Tags: javascript, java, performance, swing, email

I have a code which has always worked in sending via mail pec on Aruba.
At one time, it did not work anymore. When I compiled, it returns:

```
Exception reading response
Exception reading response
Exception reading response
Exception reading response
Exception reading response
Exception reading response
Exception reading response
Exception reading response
Exception reading response
```

Using a sniffer program, I saw that the problem is related to "certified unknown".

Here is my code:

```java
//********************************************************
    public static boolean sendMail(String Messaggio, String mailDest) {
        boolean stato = true;
        try {
            stato = true;
            DataHandler dh = null;
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", Main.conf.getSmtp());
            //attivare pec
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, authenticator );            
            javax.mail.Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress(Main.conf.getMittenteMail());            
            InternetAddress to[] = InternetAddress.parse(mailDest);

            message.setFrom(from);
            message.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
            message.setSubject("AVVISO DI SCADENZA RIBA");
            message.setSentDate(new Date());

            // NUOVA GESTIONE MAIL : Testo + Allegato

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            // crea la parte testuale
            BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart(); 
            messageBodyPart1.setContent(Messaggio.toString(),"text/html"); 
        //  messageBodyPart1.setText(Messaggio);

            //  Crea l'allegato , disattivata.
            //  DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
          //BodyPart messageBodyPart2 = new MimeBodyPart(); 
        //  messageBodyPart2.setContent("<b>Sollecito Riba:<\b>", "text/html");
            //  mp.addBodyPart(bpHTML)

            // messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

            /*File fFile = new File("C:\\folder\\prova.txt");
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(fFile);  ALLEGATO
            dh = new DataHandler(source);
            messageBodyPart2.setDataHandler(dh);
            messageBodyPart2.setFileName(fFile.getName());
*/
            // aggiunge le parti all'oggetto multipart
            //multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1); //html
            //multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart2);

            // imposta come contenuto del messaggio l'oggetto multipart
            message.setContent(multipart);
            // Transport.send(message);
            // FINE NUOVA GESTIONE: Testo + Allegato

            javax.mail.Transport.send(message);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            stato = false;
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return stato;
    }
```

What should I do? What happened? Why it was working but not anymore?